# java.utilNoSuchElementException: None.get for Vec

Tags: chisel

Perhaps I'm going about something the wrong way.  I have a number of buffers that need to get locked and unlocked as part of the behavior of a state machine.  I thought it would be perfect to use a Vec of Reg to store the state from clock to clock and use a var Vec of wires to accumulate the state as the state machine goes about locking and unlocking things.  Here is code similar to the code I wrote that breaks in the same way:

```
import Chisel._

class testvec extends Module
{
    val io = new Bundle
    {
        val addr    = Vec( 5, UInt( INPUT, 4 ) )
        val enable  = Bool( INPUT )
        val in      = Vec( 5, UInt( INPUT, 16 ) )
        val out     = Vec( 16, UInt( OUTPUT, 16 ) )
    }

    val latch = Vec( 16, Reg( init=UInt(0,16) ) )
    var temp = Vec( 16, UInt(0,16) )
    for( i <- 0 until 16 )
    {
        temp(i) := latch(i)
    }
    for( i <- 0 until 5 )
    {
        temp(io.addr(i)) := io.in(i)
    }
    for( i <- 0 until 16 )
    {
        io.out(i) := temp(i)
    }
    when( io.enable )
    {
        for( i <- 0 until 16 )
        {
            latch(i) := temp(i)
        }
    }
}

class testvec_Tests(c: testvec) extends Tester(c)
{
    step( 1 )
}

object mainStub
{
    def main( args: Array[String] ): Unit =
    {
        chiselMainTest( Array[String]("--backend", "c", // "--backend", "v",
                "--compile", "--test", "--genHarness"),
                () => Module( new testvec() ) )
        {
            c => new testvec_Tests( c )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that although this code merely has a simple loop, I need to get my combinatorial lock state at various points during the execution of the state machine each clock cycle, so that's why this simplification has those combinatorial states as the final output rather than the registers.

Here's the full text of the error message:

```
[info] Set current project to chisel
[info] Running mainStub 
[error] (run-main-0) java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at Chisel.ROMData$$anonfun$3.apply(ROM.scala:90)
    at Chisel.ROMData$$anonfun$3.apply(ROM.scala:90)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.immutable.RedBlackTree$TreeIterator.foreach(RedBlackTree.scala:468)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at Chisel.ROMData.<init>(ROM.scala:90)
    at Chisel.ROM.data$lzycompute(ROM.scala:72)
    at Chisel.ROM.data(ROM.scala:72)
    at Chisel.ROM.read(ROM.scala:77)
    at Chisel.Vec.apply(Vec.scala:121)
    at testvec$$anonfun$2.apply$mcVI$sp(testvec.scala:21)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
    at testvec.<init>(testvec.scala:19)
    at mainStub$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(testvec.scala:47)
    at mainStub$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(testvec.scala:47)
    at Chisel.Module$.Chisel$Module$$init(Module.scala:65)
    at Chisel.Module$.apply(Module.scala:50)
    at mainStub$$anonfun$main$1.apply(testvec.scala:47)
    at mainStub$$anonfun$main$1.apply(testvec.scala:47)
    at Chisel.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:101)
    at Chisel.Driver$.apply(Driver.scala:41)
    at Chisel.Driver$.apply(Driver.scala:64)
    at Chisel.chiselMain$.apply(hcl.scala:63)
    at Chisel.chiselMainTest$.apply(hcl.scala:76)
    at mainStub$.main(testvec.scala:48)
    at mainStub.main(testvec.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 3, 2016 1:49:17 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of your "Vec" declaration ?
According to [documentation](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/getting-started.html#x1-330004.2), Vec must be declared as following I think:

```
val io = new Bundle
{
    val addr    = Vec.fill(5) {UInt( INPUT, 4 )}
    val enable  = Bool( INPUT )
    val in      = Vec.fill( 5 ) {UInt( INPUT, 16 )}
    val out     = Vec.fill( 16 ) {UInt( OUTPUT, 16 )}
}
```

Comment: Both these syntax variations work, with the one you list above sometimes being slightly more useful.  I know both to be legal and problem-free.